# When to use select_at, mutate_at, etc. functions?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been playing around with the `verb_at`, `verb_if`, `verb_each` functions from `dplyr`.

The examples that I found show usecases only for `verb_if` and `verb_all`.

Could someone give some use cases for the rest of the functions.

Comment: The `example` function is very useful when you are looking for examples. For instance, `example("mutate_at", package = "dplyr")` and you can find a usage for `summarise_at`: `starwars %>% summarise_at(vars(height:mass), mean, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Plus you can check `dplr`'s [page](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) to check what each one does.

Comment: `verb_each` functions are deprecated in favor of `verb_all`, `verb_at`, `verb_if` functions, according to the help (see `?mutate_each`, for instance). That narrows your list a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `?select_vars` and `?select_helpers` from the `dplyr` help. The purpose of the `verb_at` functions is to use the `select_helpers` functions to select variables based on the variable name or index and apply the function to that. Some examples:

```
data(iris)

# Convert all columns containing Sepal data to integers
x <- mutate_at(iris, vars(contains("Sepal")), as.integer)
head(x)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1            5           3          1.4         0.2  setosa
2            4           3          1.4         0.2  setosa
3            4           3          1.3         0.2  setosa
4            4           3          1.5         0.2  setosa
5            5           3          1.4         0.2  setosa
6            5           3          1.7         0.4  setosa

# Summarize the mean of all variables containing "Sepal"
summarise_at(iris, vars(contains('Sepal')), mean)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
1     5.843333    3.057333
```

`select_at` is generally not needed, since `select` is already scoped and accepts `select_helpers`. As [this answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54076710/8366499), the one advantage of using `select_at` is that it allows you to apply a function to rename the selected variables:

```
data(starwars)

# Select Variables
select(starwars, ends_with('Color')) %>%
    head()

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  hair_color  skin_color  eye_color
  <chr>       <chr>       <chr>    
1 blond       fair        blue     
2 NA          gold        yellow   
3 NA          white, blue red      
4 none        white       yellow   
5 brown       light       brown    
6 brown, grey light       blue 

# Select and rename variables
select_at(starwars, vars(ends_with('Color')), toupper) %>%
    head
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  HAIR_COLOR  SKIN_COLOR  EYE_COLOR
  <chr>       <chr>       <chr>    
1 blond       fair        blue     
2 NA          gold        yellow   
3 NA          white, blue red      
4 none        white       yellow   
5 brown       light       brown    
6 brown, grey light       blue
```

Comment: Could you ellaborate a bit more how `select_at(starwars, vars(ends_with('Color')))` differs from the goold old `select(starwars, ends_with("Color"))`? The latter is shorter and seems to give the same result.

Comment: @HolgerBrandl You're right that there is really no reason to use `select_at` here. The only difference is that it lets you rename variables while selecting them and my guess is that it only exists for consistency with the naming patterns of the other dplyr functions.