# What is select_at() for?

Tags: r, dplyr

I understand how to use `dplyr::select_if()` and `dplyr::mutate_at()`. But I don't understand what `dplyr::select_at()` provides that a basic `select()` doesn't provide.

As far as I understand, the `verb_at()` functions allow you to utilize the select helper functions (like `matches()` and `starts_with()`). But `select()` already uses the select helpers--so why would you use `select_at()` instead of just `select()`?

Comment: `select_at` also has a `.funs=` parameter you can use. Such as `select_at(mtcars, names(mtcars), funs(toupper(.)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary benefit of `select_at()` (as opposed to the vanilla `select()`) is that it provides an `.funs=` parameter so that you can use a function, eg. `toupper()` to rename files as you select them.

This makes a ton of sense for something like `rename_at()`. Providing similar functionality with `select_at()` makes sense from a tidyverse-style "everything works the same" perspective.